# How to raise an error from a script called from psql -f my_script.sql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm doing the following in a sql script which I call by doing `psql -f my_script.sql`:

```sql
select not exists(select 1 from pg_class where relname='my_table') as my_table_not_exists
\gset
\if :my_table_not_exists
    -- raise error
\endif
```

How can I return a non-0 status code and write `table 'table_name' doesn't exist` to stderr there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `ON_ERROR_STOP` and then use the table, then you will get the error message as desired, and processing will terminate:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FALSE;
```

You can output an arbitrary message to standard output:

```
\! echo 'Hello!' 1>&2
```

But there is no way to exit `psql` with a non-zero return code except to cause a database error.

Maybe you should use a bash script with a `psql` co-process for more fancy processing.

Comment: Is it possible to use `\! echo message 1>&2` and then return an exit code?  Simply doing `\! exit 1` doesn't seem to work... I would like to return a custom error message

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set on the ON_ERROR_STOP

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
select * from Table Name; 
\unset ON_ERROR_STOP
```

Please refer [this](http://dwgeek.com/redshift-set-on_error_stop-using-psql-examples.html/)